# Como hacer que los valores de un FORM se guarden en JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Es la primera vez que escribo, pero realmente ya no se como solucionarlo.
Empecé hace un mes con Javascript, estoy queriendo hacer un form que cuando se envié la información se almacene.
Les muestro:

```
document.querySelector('#EnvioSolicitud').addEventListener('click', guardarSolicitud);

 function guardarSolicitud(){
    let sNombre = document.querySelector('txtName').value,
        sCelular = document.querySelector('txtCelular').value,
        sCorreo= document.querySelector('txtCorreo').value,
        sMensaje= document.querySelector('txtMensaje').value;   

 addAdoptionPet(sNombre,sCelular,sCorreo,sMensaje);
 }
 
 
 let AdoptionList = [];

 function addAdoptionPet(pname,pphone,pemail,pmessage) {

            let newAdoption = {
               nombre: pname,
               celular: pphone,
               email: pemail,
               mensaje: pmessage
            };
            console.log(newAdoption);
            AdoptionList.push(newAdoption);
            localStorageAdoptionList(AdoptionList)
 }

function getAdoptionList(){
   let storedList =localStorage.getItem('localAdoptionList');
   if(storedList == null){
      AdoptionList =[]; 
   }else{
      AdoptionList = JSON.parse(storedList);
   }
   return AdoptionList;
}

function localStorageAdoptionList(plist){
   localStorage.setItem('localAdoptionList', JSON.stringify(plist));
}
```

realmente envio la info, y no me aparece ningun ERROR ni nada, se vuelve a cargar la pagina y no me muestra la informacion

Comment: Quieres que se guarden en el localStorage?

Comment: debes publicar completo el codigo para que te podamos ayudar. donde usas la función getAdoptionList??

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en `guardarSolicitud()` estarías intentando alcanzar los valores de los `input` del formulario, pero esos `querySelector` no funcionarán. Si quieres alcanzar los elementos por su id, debes poner en primer lugar `#` ... pero eso no hace falta, puedes simplificar tu código usando [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) como veremos. El uso de `FormData` por ejemplo te permite serializar todo tu formulario con una sola línea de código, de modo que con `Object.fromEntries()` tendrías todos los valores listos para guardarlos en localStorage.

Aparte de eso, habría que buscar la forma de guardar colecciones de objetos en localStorage. Con algo como esto: `localData = localData.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localAdoptionList') || '[]'));`, cuando haya valores, se concantenarán como objetos independientes dentro de la clave `localAdoptionList`.

El código podría quedar así:

```
localStorage.removeItem('localAdoptionList');

document.getElementById('EnvioSolicitud').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addAdoptionList(e.target);
});

function addAdoptionList(form) {
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  var json = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  var localData = [];
  localData.push(json);
  localData = localData.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localAdoptionList') || '[]'));
  localStorage.setItem('localAdoptionList', JSON.stringify(localData));
  showAdoptionList();
}

function showAdoptionList() {
  let savedData = localStorage.getItem('localAdoptionList');
  console.log(JSON.parse(savedData));
}
```

#### Demo

Aquí te dejo un <kbd>[**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/9k0p1v8x/66/)</kbd> donde podrás hacer pruebas. Intenta por ejemplo enviar varias veces el `form`, verás que cada vez se crea un nuevo objeto. Por supuesto, si eso no interesa, no será difícil modificar tu código para que guarde un solo elemento, si tal es el propósito.